# Update Grid-Row Element

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to change the value of an element in a class using javascript?

```
    .poTomorrow{
 grid-row: 3/span 2;
 grid-column: 6/span 1;
 }
```

For example, would I be able to change value of grid-row to 4/span 4 using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not, but you can change html elements class or directly add an inline style to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
    let $elem = $('.poTomorrow');
    console.log('grid-row', $elem.css('grid-row'));
    $elem.css('grid-row', '4/span 4');
    console.log('grid-row', $elem.css('grid-row'));
```

```css
        .poTomorrow {
            grid-row: 3/span 2;
            grid-column: 6/span 1;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="poTomorrow">poTomorrow</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the other answers haven't mentioned this but you could simply access the style of the object using pure JS.

```
const htmlElement = document.querySelector("#elementId");
htmlElement.style.gridRow = "4 / span 4";
```

For a class though, you might need to loop through them to update.

```
const classElements = document.querySelectorAll(".poTomorrow");
for (i = 0; i < classElements.length; i++) {
  classElements[i].style.gridRow = "4 / span 4";
}
```